# grokparsefailure with multiple if [type] - logstash config

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, elastic-stack

Ok - I've been racking my head over this config file for days with little success (I'm very new to logstash/ELK stack).  The problem I'm having is when I place two logstash configs in the same directory I get a grok error on the second config.  Meaning, 001 will work and 002 will produce the error.  If I run logstash with only one config (doesn't matter which one) everything runs great.  When combined, one works the other fails.  I have combined the two conf files into a single conf file but the same issue persists.  Below is the combined version of the config and a sample of the syslogs. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```
input {
  file {
    path => ["/var/log/pantraffic.log"]
    #start_position => "beginning"
    type => "pantraffic"
  }
   file {
    path => ["/var/log/panthreat.log"]
    #start_position => "beginning"
    type => "panthreat"
  } 
}

filter {
  if [type] == "pantraffic" {
    grok {
      #patterns_dir => "/opt/logstash/patterns"
      match => [ "message_traffic", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:@timestamp} %       {HOSTNAME:syslog_host} %{GREEDYDATA:traffic_message}"]
    }
    syslog_pri { }
  }
   csv {
      source => "traffic_message"
columns => [ "PaloAltoDomain","ReceiveTime","SerialNum","Type","Threat-   ContentType","ConfigVersion","GenerateTime","SourceAddress","DestinationAddress","NATSourceIP","NATDestinationIP","Rule","SourceUser","DestinationUser","Application","VirtualSystem","SourceZone","DestinationZone","InboundInterface","OutboundInterface","LogAction","TimeLogged","SessionID","RepeatCount","SourcePort","DestinationPort","NATSourcePort","NATDestinationPort","Flags","IPProtocol","Action","Bytes","BytesSent","BytesReceived","Packets","StartTime","ElapsedTimeInSec","Category","Padding","seqno","actionflags","SourceCountry","DestinationCountry","cpadding","pkts_sent","pkts_received","sessionEndReason" ]
}

 date {
      #timezone => "America/Chicago"
      match => [ "GenerateTime", "YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" ]    
}

mutate {
      convert => [ "Bytes", "integer" ]
      convert => [ "BytesReceived", "integer" ]
      convert => [ "BytesSent", "integer" ]
      convert => [ "ElapsedTimeInSec", "integer" ]
      convert => [ "geoip.area_code", "integer" ]
      convert => [ "geoip.dma_code", "integer" ]
      convert => [ "geoip.latitude", "float" ]
      convert => [ "geoip.longitude", "float" ]
      convert => [ "NATDestinationPort", "integer" ]
      convert => [ "NATSourcePort", "integer" ]
      convert => [ "Packets", "integer" ]
      convert => [ "pkts_received", "integer" ]
      convert => [ "pkts_sent", "integer" ]
      convert => [ "seqno", "integer" ]
      gsub => [ "Rule", " ", "_",
                "Application", "( |-)", "_" ]
      remove_field => [ "message_traffic", "traffic_message" ]
    }

if [SourceAddress] and [SourceAddress] !~ "(^127\.0\.0\.1)|(^10\.)|(^172\.1[6-   9]\.)|(^172\.2[0-9]\.)|(^172\.3[0-1]\.)|(^192\.168\.)|(^169\.254\.)" {
      geoip {
           database => "/opt/logstash/GeoLiteCity.dat"
           source => "SourceAddress"
           target => "SourceGeo"
      }
      if ([SourceGeo.location] and [SourceGeo.location] =~ "0,0") {
        mutate {
          replace => [ "SourceGeo.location", "" ]
        }
      }
    }
if [DestinationAddress] and [DestinationAddress] !~ "(^127\.0\.0\.1)|(^10\.)|(^172\.1[6-9]\.)|(^172\.2[0-9]\.)|(^172\.3[0-1]\.)|(^192\.168\.)|(^169\.254\.)" {
      geoip {
           database => "/opt/logstash/GeoLiteCity.dat"
           source => "DestinationAddress"
           target => "DestinationGeo"
      }

      if ([DestinationGeo.location] and [DestinationGeo.location] =~ "0,0") {
        mutate {
          replace => [ "DestinationAddress.location", "" ]
        }
      }
    }

  if [SourceAddress] and [DestinationAddress] {
    fingerprint {
      concatenate_sources => true
      method => "SHA1"
      key => "logstash"
      source => [ "SourceAddress", "SourcePort", "DestinationAddress",  "DestinationPort", "IPProtocol" ]
    }
  }
###########################################################################
if [type] == "panthreat" {
    grok {

      match => [ "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:@timestamp} % {HOSTNAME:syslog_host} %{GREEDYDATA:threat_message}"]
    }
        syslog_pri { }
  }
   csv {
      source => "threat_message"
columns => [ "Domain","ReceiveTime","Serial","Type","ThreatContentType","ConfigVersion","GenerateTime","SourceAddress","DestinationAddress","NATSourceIP","NATDestinationIP","Rule","SourceUser","DestinationUser","Application","VirtualSystem","SourceZone","DestinationZone","InboundInterface","OutboundInterface","LogAction","TimeLogged","SessionID","RepeatCount","SourcePort","DestinationPort","NATSourcePort","NATDestinationPort","Flags","IPProtocol","Action","URL","ThreatContentName","Category","Severity","Direction","seqno","actionflags","SourceCountry","DestinationCountry","cpadding","contenttype","pcap_id","filedigest","cloud","url_idx","user_agent","filetype","xff","referer","sender","subject","recipient","reportid" ]
}

date {
      #timezone => "America/Chicago"
      match => [ "GenerateTime", "YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" ]
}

mutate {
      #convert => [ "Bytes", "integer" ]
      #convert => [ "BytesReceived", "integer" ]
      #convert => [ "BytesSent", "integer" ]
      #convert => [ "ElapsedTimeInSec", "integer" ]
      convert => [ "geoip.area_code", "integer" ]
      convert => [ "geoip.dma_code", "integer" ]
      convert => [ "geoip.latitude", "float" ]
      convert => [ "geoip.longitude", "float" ]
      convert => [ "NATDestinationPort", "integer" ]
      convert => [ "NATSourcePort", "integer" ]
      #convert => [ "Packets", "integer" ]
      #convert => [ "pkts_received", "integer" ]
      #convert => [ "pkts_sent", "integer" ]
      #convert => [ "seqno", "integer" ]
      gsub => [ "Rule", " ", "_",
                "Application", "( |-)", "_" ]
      remove_field => [ "message", "threat_message" ]
    }

if [SourceAddress] and [SourceAddress] !~ "(^127\.0\.0\.1)|(^10\.)|(^172\.1[6- 9]\.)|(^172\.2[0-9]\.)|(^172\.3[0-1]\.)|(^192\.168\.)|(^169\.254\.)" {
      geoip {
           database => "/opt/logstash/GeoLiteCity.dat"
           source => "SourceAddress"
           target => "SourceGeo"
      }
      if ([SourceGeo.location] and [SourceGeo.location] =~ "0,0") {
        mutate {
          replace => [ "SourceGeo.location", "" ]
        }
      }
    }
 if [DestinationAddress] and [DestinationAddress] !~ "(^127\.0\.0\.1)|(^10\.)|(^172\.1[6-9]\.)|(^172\.2[0-9]\.)|(^172\.3[0-1]\.)|(^192\.168\.)|(^169\.254\.)" {
      geoip {
           database => "/opt/logstash/GeoLiteCity.dat"
           source => "DestinationAddress"
           target => "DestinationGeo"
      }

      if ([DestinationGeo.location] and [DestinationGeo.location] =~ "0,0") {
        mutate {
          replace => [ "DestinationAddress.location", "" ]
         }
       }
    }

  if [SourceAddress] and [DestinationAddress] {
    fingerprint {
      concatenate_sources => true
      method => "SHA1"
      key => "logstash"
      source => [ "SourceAddress", "SourcePort", "DestinationAddress",  "DestinationPort", "IPProtocol" ]
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Log Samples:

```
panthreat log:
015-11-13T04:53:28-06:00 PA-200 1,2015/11/13    04:53:28,0011122223333,THREAT,vulnerability,1,2015/11/13 04:53:28,73.222.111.1,4.4.4.4,0.0.0.0,0.0.0.0,rule1,,,dns,vsys1,trust,untrust,ethernet1/2,ethernet1/1,Default_Forwarder,2015/11/13 04:53:28,3602,1,34830,53,0,0,0x0,udp,drop-all-packets,"",Test(41000),0,any,high,client-to-server,37,0x0,US,US,0,,0,,,0,,,,,,,

pantraffic log:
2015-11-13T07:34:22-06:00 PA-200 1,2015/11/13 07:34:21,001112223334,TRAFFIC,end,1,2015/11/13 07:34:21,73.22.111.1,4.3.2.1,0.0.0.0,0.0.0.0,rule1,,,facebook-base,vsys1,trust,untrust,ethernet1/2,ethernet1/1,Default_Forwarder,2015/11/13 07:34:21,6385,1,63121,443,0,0,0x53,tcp,allow,6063,2285,3778,29,2015/11/13 07:34:05,2,social-networking,0,15951,0x0,US,IE,0,17,12,tcp-fin
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you messed up your closing brackets. Check this block (your first if) 
for instance:

```
  if [type] == "pantraffic" {
    grok {
      #patterns_dir => "/opt/logstash/patterns"
      match => [ "message_traffic", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:@timestamp} %       {HOSTNAME:syslog_host} %{GREEDYDATA:traffic_message}"]
    }
    syslog_pri { }
  }
```

The last closing bracket is likely wrong here. You don't want to close your if block here but just before you start your "panthreat" block further down. The "panthreat" if block has the same problem.

Comment: @whistler585 hi plz accept my answer if it was helpful to you. thx